What would cause error BC30235 in the server code below
I am trying to develop a floating network licence app. my server code is given below.
But the line: <RunInstaller(True)> _
throws an error.
Error   BC32035 Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement.
What would cause this error?
    Imports System
    Imports System.ServiceProcess
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Threading


    Public Class LicenceService

Inherits ServiceBase

Private _listener As TcpListener
Private _listenerThread As Thread
Private _running As Boolean = False

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    _running = True
    _listenerThread = New Thread(AddressOf StartListener)
    _listenerThread.Start()
End Sub



Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    _running = False
    If _listener IsNot Nothing Then
        _listener.Stop()
    End If
    If _listenerThread IsNot Nothing Then
        _listenerThread.Join()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub StartListener()
    _listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12345)
    _listener.Start()

    While _running
        If _listener.Pending() Then
            Dim client As TcpClient = _listener.AcceptTcpClient()
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf HandleClient, client)
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(100) ' Reduce CPU usage
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub HandleClient(ByVal clientObj As Object)
    Dim client As TcpClient = CType(clientObj, TcpClient)
    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
    Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
    Dim bytesRead As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    Dim request As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead)

    ' Process request (e.g., check out a license)
    Dim response As String = "License granted"
    Dim responseBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response)
    stream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length)

    client.Close()
End Sub

    End Class

'''
and
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Configuration.Install
    Imports System.ServiceProcess

    <RunInstaller(True)> _

Public Class ProjectInstaller

Inherits Installer

Private serviceInstaller As ServiceInstaller
Private processInstaller As ServiceProcessInstaller

Public Sub New()
    processInstaller = New ServiceProcessInstaller()
    serviceInstaller = New ServiceInstaller()

    ' Service will run under system account
    processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem

    ' Service Information
    serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "License Server Service"
    serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic
    serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "LicenseServerService"

    ' Add installers to collection. Order is not important.
    Installers.Add(serviceInstaller)
    Installers.Add(processInstaller)
    End Sub
    End Class


Delete the empty line after the attribute

Read the notes here: How do I fix Error BC32035 - Attribute specifier is not a complete statement?
